# if a record is submitted for approval to different users,if any one of them approves or rejects it should reflects to all other users

Tags: salesforce1-app, approval-process, salesforce-id, error-messages

I have written custom code to submit record for approval to different users.assume there are 10 users received approval requests among those at-least one user approves or rejects record the status of the approve/reject should be reflects to all other users(when they open email link they should see approve/reject status not "pending" status).Here i am able to submit request to all emails which i specified in code.please guide me

### Code:

```
public static void submitRequestForApproval(Account acc){
        integer intRegion;
        set<string> strEmails = new set<string>();
        set<id> userId = new set<id>();
       if(acc.place__c!= null){
           intRegion = integer.valueOf(acc.place__c);
       }
       list<user> userList = [select id,email from user where Email IN: strEmails];
       list<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> reqList = new list<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>(); 
       for(user use : userList){
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req.setComments('Submitted request for approval');
        req.setObjectId(acc.id);
        req.setNextApproverIds(new id[] {use.id});
        reqList.add(req);
       }

       list<Approval.ProcessResult> result = Approval.process(reqList);
   }
```

Comment: You didn't mention whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: now i am able to submit for approval but how can achieve "if a record is submitted for approval to different users,if any one of them approves or rejects it should reflects to all other users"

Answer (score 2):

> If a record is submitted for approval to different users,if any one of them approves or rejects it should reflects to all other users

**Solution**

In the Approval Steps, at Step 3: Select Assigned Approver, choose `Approve or Reject based on FIRST Response`.

[image: Select Assigned Approver]